# Persist session data Django

Tags: django, django-sessions

i need to migrate session  data to the another table in database at the time of its destruction (for example, when the browser is closed or when expired date). 
I read that session doesn't clear itself , i need do it manualy .

Answer (score 1):

Django sessions are persisted to the db by default.

Read the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-store

**Update:**

The only situation where Django 'knows' the session has expired is when the user logs out manually. In this case you could connect to the [`user_logged_out` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_out) to do your data migration.

Otherwise the old session data stays in the db. Django provides the [`clearsessions` management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-clearsessions) to delete old sessions. They suggest you run it daily on the crontab.

You could write your own version of that command which also does your data migration.

Comment: i already read this , but i need to migrate data from session to another table , when it's destruct